# How to use String.substring?

Tags: arduino-uno, string, pointer

I have the following code in which `requestLine` is always empty and I can't figure out why. `request` contains a raw HTTP request, and I want to get the first line of the request which contains the method and the URL.

```
boolean parseRequest(String* request)
{
  int firstEOLAt = request->indexOf('\n');
  if (firstEOLAt < 0)
    return false;
  Serial.println(firstEOLAt);
  String requestLine = request->substring(0, firstEOLAt);
  Serial.println(requestLine);
  // ...rest of the parsing will go here...
  return true;
}
```

The first `println` returns 26 as you would expect for the string `"GET /ilyen_nincs HTTP/1.1"` (25 characters long), but then `requestLine` is always empty. I wonder why?

Answer (score 2):

`GET /ilyen_nincs HTTP/1.1\n` is 26 characters long so string indices are from 0 to 25. Since, your second argument in `substring(0, firstEOLAt);` exceeds the end index of the string, you are running into unexpected behavior as per the [documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringSubstring) and getting an empty string.

> Caution: make sure your index values are within the String's length or you'll get unpredictable results. This kind of error can be particularly hard to find with the second instance of substring() if the starting position is less than the String's length, but the ending position isn't.